# mapPartitionsWithIndex for Spark Datasets

Tags: apache-spark-dataset

Does anyone know why **mapPartitionsWithIndex** is only available for RDDs but **not for Datasets**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add example where its happening

Comment: Actually I do not have an example. I was just wondering because mapPartitions exists for both (RDDs and Datasets) but mapPartitionsWithIndex is only available for RDDs.